# Mysteriously appearing required NT authentication after Classic ASP site update?

Tags: iis, asp-classic

A developer posts their code from a staging site (which requires authentication) to the live public site (which should not) and suddenly the live site is requiring authentication (which is not good).

They don't have permissions to change any settings on the server(s) and there is no call from the code on the live site to anything on the staging site, that I can locate. (No forgotten calls to an image on the staging site or anything)

Can the group think of some file that might have been removed/changed that could cause this to happen? I checked this question as well - [HTTP Authentication in ASP Classic via IIS] - but none of those methods are being used.

App is Classic ASP, IIS6.0 server.
Security Settings - Anonymous Access permitted on the live site. Account for anonymous internet users allowed read access to the directory where the site is located - user is unable to change directory or site permissions on the server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the files retain their security permissions from the folder they were copied from? Reset the permissions on the files.

Are you using a four-part URL to get to the site (http://www.somesite.com/)? That will default to the Internet zone and not intranet, prompting for authentication.

Comment: The site was Internet zone previously, before the file update - that has not appeared to change from this morning to this afternoon.

Comment: Turns out the dev had overwritten all the contents of the site directory. Restoring from backup and only moving over the files that had changed fixed it up a treat.

I'm still curious about which folder/permission it was - but I'll sort that out later. :D

Answer (score 0):

User will get challenged when Anonymous Access is turned off in IIS. What are the security settings? Without that information, we will not be able to help much.

Comment: Security settings information added - thanks for reminding me :)